# ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-00904

I tried to write the following inner join query using an Oracle database:

```
 SELECT Employee.EMPLID as EmpID, 
        Employee.FIRST_NAME AS Name,
        Team.DEPARTMENT_CODE AS TeamID, 
        Team.Department_Name AS teamname
 FROM PS_TBL_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS Employee
 INNER JOIN PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS Team 
 ON Team.DEPARTMENT_CODE = Employee.DEPTID
```

That gives the below error:

```
 INNER JOIN PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS Team ON Team.DEPARTMENT_CODE = Employee.DEPTID
                                              *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "TEAM"."DEPARTMENT_CODE": invalid identifier
```

The DDL of one table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "HRMS"."PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS"
(
  "Company Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Company Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Sector_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Sector_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Business_Unit_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Business_Unit_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Department_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Department_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  "HR_ORG_ID" VARCHAR2(255),
  "HR_ORG_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  "Cost_Center_Number" VARCHAR2(255),
  " " VARCHAR2(255)
)
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS
```

Comment: Are you sure the column name Department_Code is spelled correctly?

Comment: Yes there is a column Department_Code

Comment: **TL;DR:** use single quotes `''`.

Comment: In my case it was a calculated column that did not existe in data base.

Comment: I had to use double quotes for snowflake.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Your problem is those pernicious double quotes.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "APC"."PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS"
  2  (
  3    "Company Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  4    "Company Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  5    "Sector_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  6    "Sector_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  7    "Business_Unit_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
  8    "Business_Unit_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
  9    "Department_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
 10    "Department_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
 11    "HR_ORG_ID" VARCHAR2(255),
 12    "HR_ORG_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
 13    "Cost_Center_Number" VARCHAR2(255),
 14    " " VARCHAR2(255)
 15  )
 16  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

Oracle SQL allows us to ignore the case of database object names provided we either create them with names all in upper case, or without using double quotes.  If we use mixed case or  lower case in the script and wrapped the identifiers in double quotes we are condemned to using double quotes and the precise case whenever we refer to the object or its attributes:

```
SQL> select count(*) from PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS
  2  where Department_Code = 'BAH'
  3  /
where Department_Code = 'BAH'
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "DEPARTMENT_CODE": invalid identifier


SQL> select count(*) from PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS
  2  where "Department_Code" = 'BAH'
  3  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

---

**tl;dr**

don't use double quotes in DDL scripts

(I know most third party code generators do, but they are disciplined enough to put all their object names in UPPER CASE.)

---

The reverse is also true. If we create the table without using double-quotes …

```
create table PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS
( company_code VARCHAR2(255),
  company_name VARCHAR2(255),
  Cost_Center_Number VARCHAR2(255))
;
```

… we can reference it and its columns in whatever case takes our fancy:

```
select * from ps_tbl_department_details
```

… or

```
select * from PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS;
```

… or

```
select * from PS_Tbl_Department_Details
where COMAPNY_CODE = 'ORCL'
and cost_center_number = '0980'
```

Comment: Pernicious doesn't even begin to describe the level of frustration Oracle causes with these nonstandard practices.

Comment: Oracle sucks. Horrible program.

Comment: I was doing an Oracle database link exercise mixed with join queries and this was exactly my problem. I was getting `ORA-00904: "A"."NOMBRE": invalid identifier` errors and such, and the problem was solved adding double quotes in the column names where the errors popped.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, this error occurred, due to lack of existence of column name in the table.

When i executed  "`describe tablename`" , i was not able to find the column specified in the mapping hbm file.

After altering the table, it worked fine.

Comment: Another case is the missing of the whole table.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, in this case the cause was found to be mixed case column name in the DDL for table creation.

However, if you are mixing "old style" and ANSI joins you could get the same error message even when the DDL was done properly with uppercase table name. This happened to me, and google sent me to this stackoverflow page so I thought I'd share since I was here.

```
--NO PROBLEM: ANSI syntax
SELECT A.EMPLID, B.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME
FROM PS_PERSON A
INNER JOIN PS_NAME_PWD_VW B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
INNER JOIN PS_HCR_PERSON_NM_I C ON C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
WHERE 
    LENGTH(A.EMPLID) = 9
    AND LENGTH(B.LAST_NAME) > 5
    AND LENGTH(C.LAST_NAME) > 5
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
/

--NO PROBLEM: OLD STYLE/deprecated/traditional oracle proprietary join syntax
SELECT A.EMPLID, B.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME
FROM PS_PERSON A
, PS_NAME_PWD_VW B 
, PS_HCR_PERSON_NM_I C 
WHERE 
    B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
    and C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
    and LENGTH(A.EMPLID) = 9
    AND LENGTH(B.LAST_NAME) > 5
    AND LENGTH(C.LAST_NAME) > 5
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
/
```

The two SQL statements above are equivalent and produce no error.

When you try to mix them you can get lucky, or you can get an Oracle has a ORA-00904 error.

```
--LUCKY: mixed syntax (ANSI joins appear before OLD STYLE)
SELECT A.EMPLID, B.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME
FROM 
    PS_PERSON A
    inner join PS_HCR_PERSON_NM_I C on C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
    , PS_NAME_PWD_VW B
WHERE 
    B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
    and LENGTH(A.EMPLID) = 9
    AND LENGTH(B.FIRST_NAME) > 5
    AND LENGTH(C.LAST_NAME) > 5
/

--PROBLEM: mixed syntax (OLD STYLE joins appear before ANSI)
--http://sqlfascination.com/2013/08/17/oracle-ansi-vs-old-style-joins/
SELECT A.EMPLID, B.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME
FROM 
    PS_PERSON A
    , PS_NAME_PWD_VW B
    inner join PS_HCR_PERSON_NM_I C on C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
WHERE 
    B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
    and LENGTH(A.EMPLID) = 9
    AND LENGTH(B.FIRST_NAME) > 5
    AND LENGTH(C.LAST_NAME) > 5
/
```

And the unhelpful error message that doesn't really describe the problem at all:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-12 -------------------------
ORA-00904: "A"."EMPLID": invalid identifier  Script line 6, statement line 6,
column 51
```

I was able to find some research on this in the following blog post:

- http://sqlfascination.com/2013/08/17/oracle-ansi-vs-old-style-joins/

In my case, I was attempting to manually convert from old style to ANSI style joins, and was doing so incrementally, one table at a time. This appears to have been a bad idea. Instead, it's probably better to convert all tables at once, or comment out a table and its where conditions in the original query in order to compare with the new ANSI query you are writing.

Answer (score 4):

DEPARTMENT_CODE is not a column that exists in the table Team. Check the DDL of the table to find the proper column name.

Comment: column is exist in table i checked

Comment: Can you give us the DDL of the table PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "HRMS"."PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS"
   (    "Company Code" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Company Name" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Sector_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Sector_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Business_Unit_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Business_Unit_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Department_Code" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Department_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
        "HR_ORG_ID" VARCHAR2(255),
        "HR_ORG_Name" VARCHAR2(255),
        "Cost_Center_Number" VARCHAR2(255),
        " " VARCHAR2(255)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRES

Comment: If that really is the DDL, then the columns have been created as case-sensitive. You should remove the double quotes from the column definitions. If you can't re-create the table, use Team."Department_Name" in your select statement.

Comment: I particularly like the last column name; any guesses what gets stored in there?

Comment: @Alex: I heard space is full of vacuum, so that is my guess.

Comment: Of course; in space no-one can hear you scream, so maybe it's somewhere to store all your frustrations.

Comment: Hah, good catch, I never noticed that. That's a new one to me, a space for a column name!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got this error when I tried to create a new table in Oracle like this with `,` in last line

```
create table products(
  id_pro number primary key,
  product_name varchar2(20),
);
```

By removing `,` the problem solved like this

```
create table products_test(
  id_pro number primary key,
  product_name varchar2(20)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have a column **DEPARTEMENT_CODE** on your table **PS_TBL_DEPARTMENT_DETAILS**

[More informations](http://ora-00904.ora-code.com/) about your ERROR

> ORA-00904:    string: invalid identifier
>       Cause:    The column name entered is either missing or invalid.
>       Action:   Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with a
>   letter,
>       be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only
>   alphanumeric characters and
>       the special characters $, _, and #.
>       If it contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in d  double
>   quotation marks.
>       It may not be a reserved word.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when trying to save an entity through JPA.

It was because I had a column with `@JoinColumn` annotation that didn't have `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Adding `@ManyToOne` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the user issuing the query has been granted the necessary permissions.

For queries on tables you need to grant SELECT permission.
For queries on other object types (e.g. stored procedures) you need to grant EXECUTE permission.

Comment: while its always worth checking grants. If you're missing table grants then its more likely to get the famous and equally helpful [ORA-00942 table or view does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129912/sql-error-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist/56480959)

Comment: In case of `select some_column from some_table where some_package.some_function() = 0`, when some_package has no `execute` grant for current user, I observe ORA-00904. (Ora 11g, called through Hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception and the problem in my case was due the column was not present in the sub-query - despite I know the "missing" column/identifier belongs to the table with the alias I'm referring to.

Example - *this query generates the **ORA-00904 - invalid identifier** at the column `MC.SIT_TYPE`*:

```
SELECT MC.ID_CODE,
       MC.EMP_NAME
FROM (SELECT MC.ID_CODE, 
             MC.EMP_NAME
      FROM EMP_WORKER MC) MC
INNER JOIN TEM_SHEETS FR ON MC.SIT_TYPE = FR.ID_CODE -- This line has the ORA-00904 error.
LEFT JOIN WRK_TYPE RAS ON MC.ID_CODE = RAS.ID_CODE;
```

Now, after modify the sub-query - by adding the **`MC.SIT_TYPE`** column - , the **`ORA-00904`** disapears.

Result:

```
SELECT MC.ID_CODE,
       MC.EMP_NAME
FROM (SELECT MC.ID_CODE, 
             MC.EMP_NAME, ​
            ​ -- Here, the "missing invalid identifier, in this case (MC.SIT_TYPE)" is added: 
             MC.SIT_TYPE
      FROM EMP_WORKER MC) MC
INNER JOIN TEM_SHEETS FR ON MC.SIT_TYPE = FR.ID_CODE 
LEFT JOIN WRK_TYPE RAS ON MC.ID_CODE = RAS.ID_CODE;
```

Here are some tips:

- Check very closely the tabulation/indent of your code - (*depending of your settings*), SQL Developer handles the indentation of your code different.
- The code you're working on might not be tabulated/indented - making the debugging of these kind of errors harder and time-consuming.
- Modify the aliases of your columns/sub-queries - code in general - for generate unique aliases - with this, I mean: don't use the same aliases for sub-queries and related tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception in JPA 2 using eclipse link. I had an @embedded class with one to one relationship with an entity. 
By mistake ,in the embedded class, i had also the annotation @Table("TRADER"). When the DB was created by the JPA from the entities it also created a table TRADER (which was a wrong as the Trader entity was embedded to the main entity) and the existence of that table was causing the above exception every time i was trying to persist my entity. 
After deleting the TRADER table the exception disappered.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the values without the quotes. Once I passed the conditions inside the single quotes worked like a charm.

```
Select * from emp_table where emp_id=123;
```

instead of the above use this:

```
Select * from emp_table where emp_id='123';
```

Comment: If `emp_id` is a numeric, the first statement will cause *ORA-01722: invalid number*

Answer (score 0):

I got the error message because there was an table alias i missed and didn't use.

This throws the error because of the 'cl' alias:

```
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.COMPANYLOCATION_CL cl JOIN MYSCHEMA.COMPANYTYPE_CT ON MYSCHEMA.COMPANYLOCATION_CL.CLNR = MYSCHEMA.COMPANYTYPE_CT.CT_CL_NR
```

Without 'cl' it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.COMPANYLOCATION_CL JOIN MYSCHEMA.COMPANYTYPE_CT ON MYSCHEMA.COMPANYLOCATION_CL.CLNR = MYSCHEMA.COMPANYTYPE_CT.CT_CL_NR
```

Please don't complain about the table names - the schema is 20 years old...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by using the **wrong case** for a column name and it seems you're having the same issue.

`Department_Code` isn't the same as `DEPARTMENT_CODE` for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same error from my database. My fault was that I had configured a wrong default schema for hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Query line caused the error ❌

```
SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY UserName
```

Solved by putting two single quotation ✅

```
SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY 'UserName'
```