# DbUnit doesnt see Oracle column NoSuchColumnException

Tags: java, oracle, dbunit

DbUnit settings:

```
DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_SKIP_ORACLE_RECYCLEBIN_TABLES, true);
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory());
```

Code:

```
@Test
    @DataSet(value="ReportTest.testPropagationToChild.xml", loadStrategy=RefreshLoadStrategy.class)
    public void testPropagationToChild() {
```

Dataset:

```
<dataset>
    <REPORT ID="-1" NODE_NAME="TG1" NODE_LEVEL="2" PARENT_ID="0" RENA_STATUS="1" PSR_STATUS="1" PSR_AMOUNT="200" RENA_AMOUNT="1000" PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY="u11" RENA_LAST_UPDATED_BY="u2"/>
```

Table:

```
 ID     PARENT_ID   NODE_NAME     NODE_LEVEL     RENA_STATUS     RENA_LAST_UPDATED     RENA_LAST_UPDATED_BY     RENA_AMOUNT           PSR_STATUS     PSR_LAST_UPDATED     PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY     PSR_AMOUNT     RENA_COMMENT     ADDITIONAL_COMMENT
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: REPORT.PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY -  (Non-uppercase input column: PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
```

Other columns (like ID etc) are OK for import. I'm using Oracle 11g, dbunit 2.4.8

Why it fails to import PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY?
Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution for you issue ? I've got the same right now ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your exception is telling you what's wrong:

> (Non-uppercase input column: PSR_LAST_UPDATED_BY) in
>   ColumnNameToIndexes cache map.  Note that the map's column names are
>   NOT case sensitive.

It appears to me that your column was created with mixed case, in which case it needs to be referred to in double-quotes, in exactly the case that's in the dictionary. Not sure how you do that in DBUnit. Apparently there's a "map" somewhere that defines the table's columns, and assumes upper case column names. Preferrably, the column should be renamed to all upper case.

[This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier) illustrates what I believe is going on here.