# Oracle SQL - Sub-queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I making a report in EM and I need to figure out somthing here

I have this query that I made:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    patch.host as "PHost",
    patch.home_location as "PDirectory",
    patch.home_name as "PHome",
    MAX(patch.INSTALLATION_TIME) as "Patched (Date)",
    MAX(patch.PATCH_RELEASE) as "PVersion",
    listagg(patch,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY patch) "Patches"
    FROM
    mgmt$applied_patches patch
    GROUP BY patch.host, patch.home_location,patch.home_name
    ORDER BY patch.host, patch.home_location
) "PCH",
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    T1.PROPERTY_VALUE as "MHost",
    T2.PROPERTY_VALUE as "MDirectory",
    T3.PROPERTY_VALUE as "MVersion",
    count(T4.PROPERTY_VALUE) as "Count of SID",
    listagg(T4.PROPERTY_VALUE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T4.PROPERTY_VALUE) as "SID"
    FROM
    MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES T1,
    MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES T2,
    MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES T3,
    MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES T4
    WHERE
    T1.TARGET_GUID = T2.TARGET_GUID
    and T1.TARGET_GUID = T3.TARGET_GUID
    and T1.TARGET_GUID = T4.TARGET_GUID
    and T1.PROPERTY_NAME = 'MachineName'
    and T2.PROPERTY_NAME = 'OracleHome'
    and T3.PROPERTY_NAME = 'Version'
    and T4.PROPERTY_NAME = 'SID'
    GROUP BY T1.PROPERTY_VALUE, T2.PROPERTY_VALUE, T3.PROPERTY_VALUE
) "MGM"
WHERE
PDirectory = MDirectory
```

I'm getting error ORA-00904: "MDIRECTORY":....

I tried many combinations! (PCH.PDirectory = MGM.MDirectory, ......) nothing works

cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

Comment: Hi, not really the same!

Comment: Actually it's exactly the same: ORA-00904 (invalid identifier) caused by using mixed case labels in double quotes but referencing them without double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DUMMY AS  "PDirectory" FROM DUAL) "PCH",
(SELECT DUMMY AS  "MDirectory" FROM DUAL) "MGR"
WHERE PDIRECTORY = MDIRECTORY
```

But this works:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DUMMY AS  "PDirectory" FROM DUAL) "PCH",
(SELECT DUMMY AS  "MDirectory" FROM DUAL) "MGR"
where "PCH"."PDirectory" = "MGR"."MDirectory"
```

change your query accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Mixed case names in Oracle are an abomination, and you've just been bitten by them.

Use:

```
"PDirectory" = "MDirectory"
```

.. or better still do not use special names that need quoting.