# schema_version doesn't have select permission?

Tags: oracle, flyway

I executed flyway:init with test/test as user/password and got the following output:

```
[INFO] Creating schema "MY_SCHEMA" ...
[INFO] Creating Metadata table: "MY_SCHEMA"."schema_version"
[INFO] Schema initialized with version: 1
```

Then I connected to oracle using MY_SCHEMA/flyway as user/password but I can't select on schema_version, I get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". User test cannot select on schema_version also.

How do I see what is in the schema_version table?

Thanks

Comment: i notice in your output, it said "JMS_SAFEPAY_ADM"."schema_version" . did you try `select *  from JMS_SAFEPAY_ADM."schema_version";` (as it seems to indicate it did it in lower case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#case-sensitive

The table name must be quoted to select from it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM "schema_version" worked indeed. Thank you. When I set "table" configuration to SCHEMA_VERSION, I can select without quotes and case sensitivity.