# ORA-00911: invalid character error while truncating table

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table that name is **_VERSION_HISTORY** I got ORA-00911 error while truncating this table. Oracle allow the name start with underscore(_) but throws an error while truncating it. Is it a silly mistake?

Comment: [Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle *does not* allow database object names to start with an underscore:

```
SQL> create table _T34 (col1 number);
create table _T34 (col1 number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character


SQL>
```

So you must have used double quotes when creating that table:

```
SQL> create table "_T34" (col1 number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Having done that once you must use double quotes whenever you reference that object?

```
SQL> truncate table "_T34";

Table truncated.

SQL>
```

So is it "a silly mistake"?  Yes, but alas on your part (or whoever decided on using double-quotes to circumvent Oracle's naming conventions).  [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have tried to execute SQL statement with a special charter in it. I don't think it is to do with the truncate command. You might just replace the truncate with a simple Select and test this scenario. Note that the special character might appear as white space due to the font you are using.

Comment: There is a simpler explanation.  See my answer.