# Alter Table Add Column in PL SQL loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to insert columns in a table using a for loop that iterates over a cursor.  The code is:

```
declare
    cursor Months_ET is 
        SELECT distinct to_char(FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA, 'MON-YY') as "Month_U" 
        FROM EXPORT_TABLE
        WHERE EXPORT_TABLE.FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA >= to_date('10/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') 
        AND EXPORT_TABLE.FEE_CD_ACT_SUM_ACCTG_DA  < to_date('10/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
    n integer := 1;
begin
    for mon in Months_ET loop
        dbms_output.put_line(mon."Month_U");
        execute immediate 'Alter table "Fee_CT" add('|| mon."Month_U" ||' varchar(20))';
        n := n +1;
    end loop;
end;
```

The cursor in the beginning jsut gets a list of unique month names which the dbms_output.put_line prints out as:

```
SEP-14
AUG-14
JUL-14
```

So I know the variable is not empty.

So using those results I want to add three columns for each month- yr.  However I get an invalid datatype error.  I have also tried altering to the for loop to concatenate the table name outside of the quotes like this:

```
for mon in Months_ET loop
--Month_List(n) := mon."Month_U";
dbms_output.put_line(mon."Month_U");
execute immediate 'Alter table' ||"Fee_CT" || 'add('|| mon."Month_U" ||' varchar(20))';
n := n +1;
```

But I get a message that "Table,View Or Sequence reference 'Fee_CT' not allowed in this context."  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  The actual data is much larger and covers a wider time frame so using multiple alter table statements isn't realistic.  plus the underlying data will be changing, so I need to be able to change the column names with the underlying data.

Comment: You're misusing the relational database. Those new columns ought to be normalised so that the month is an attribute of the table, or of a new table.

Comment: I understand they should be attributes, and why, but in this particular problem I have been asked to create a crosstab report. So yeah I know it's not ideal but gotta solve the problem.

Comment: Generally it's not necessary to change a table's structure to generate a specific report.  It seems like you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the PIVOT clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to create columns dynamically.But it is possible though:

> Errors :
>
> 1.Column names can only  have '_'(underscore),no other special character.        ie.,`AUG-15 --> AUG_15`
>
> 2. When using Alias names for further processing use `SUBQUERY` (Month_U )
> 3. Quotes should be properly used.
> 4. space between keywords/variable in execute statement.

```
create table Table_A
(id integer,
 date1 date
);
-- Table created.

begin
  insert into table_A values (1,trunc(sysdate) );
  insert into table_A values (2,trunc(sysdate+100) );
end;

select to_char(date1, 'MON-YY') as "Month_U" from table_A;
--AUG-15
--DEC-15

Declare
  cursor months_ET is select month_u from
            ( select to_char(date1, 'MON_YY') AS Month_U from table_A) DUAL;
  sql_stmnt varchar2(400) ;
  table_name varchar2(20) := 'Table_A';
  column_name varchar2(20) := 'New_col1';
  data_type varchar2(20) := 'date' ; -- you can change to varchar2
Begin
  FOR MON in months_ET 
  LOOP 
    sql_stmnt := ' alter table ' ||  table_name || ' add( ' || MON.MONTH_U 
    || ' ' || data_type  || ' ) ' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmnt );
    Execute immediate  sql_stmnt ;
  END LOOP;
End;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 alter table Table_A add( AUG_15 date ) 
 alter table Table_A add( DEC_15 date ) 

Table altered.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your table name and column names use non-standard characters - lower case letters, dashes.  This is a really bad idea, because it means having [to wrap every reference in double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325).  Every person who has to use your schema will curse you whenever they have to fix a `PLS-00357`, `ORA-00903` or `ORA-00904` exception because they forgot to double-quote an identifier.  Look, it's even caught you out :)

But if you really want to persist, the statement you need is:

```
execute immediate 'Alter table "Fee_CT" add("'|| mon."Month_U" ||"' varchar(20))';
```

The table name is part of the boilerplate text not a variable.  You need to wrap the non-standard column name in double-quotes.  Make sure the boilerplate has spaces around the key-words.

Above all, remember that a syntax error in dynamic SQL throws a runtime error, not a compilation error.  Use logging or DBMS_OUTPUT to review the assembled statements.

Answer (score 0):

Always use a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to test your `execute immediate` statement.

- Give space between keywords/variables.
- Use single quotes

Now Check this Example:

```
create table Table_A(id integer);
 -- Table created.

Declare
  sql_stmnt varchar2(400) ;
  table_name varchar2(20) := 'Table_A';
  column_name varchar2(20) := 'New_col1';
  data_type varchar2(20) := 'varchar2(20)' ;
Begin
  sql_stmnt := ' alter table ' || table_name || ' add( ' || Column_name || ' ' || data_type  || ' ) ' ;
  execute immediate  sql_stmnt ;
  dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmnt );
End;

 -- alter table Table_A add( New_col1 varchar2(20) ) 
 -- Table altered.

Desc Table_A;

   Column   Data Type   Length  Precision   Scale
     ID      NUMBER     22  -   0   -   -   -
   NEW_COL1  VARCHAR2   20  -   -   -       -   -
```