# Does Hibernate need the column name within an Entity to work?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

Within Hibernate I constantly get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "TABLE_"."COLUMNNAME": invalid identifier
```

It only ever seems to be when I have:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private String bankID;
```

Rather than e.g:

```
@Column(name = "BANK_ID", nullable=false)
private String bankID;
```

Is it necessary to have the column name for every field within my entities?

Comment: Otherwise how will hibernate know which column value to map it to?

Comment: @VishalKamat it knows using the name of the field

Comment: Is bankID the ID of your entity or a normal field?

Comment: what version of hibernate you're using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORA-00904: "TABLE_"."COLUMNNAME": invalid identifier
```

Is actually an oracle error, you can see its cause here : [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

The problem is probably that with the name of column set to "bankID", as the previous question says the column must be referred to from now on with double quotes, I probably think that `bankID` is primary/foreign key, hibernate tries to refer to it without double quotes and thus the error.

Now when you write `Column(name="BANK_ID",...`, you're following the previous question's advice : put all characters in upper case.

Honestly I don't know if you can consider this a Hibernate bug or opinion(maybe they should mention it in the docs), if it was already filed as a bug and got fixed then upgrading would solve your issue.

### Note

every error that starts with `ORA` is probably an oracle error, you can google the number after it (`00904`) and you'll mostly get answers .

Answer (score 0):

This can be customized by setting NamingStrategyDelegate (or NamingStrategy in old version) on Configuration. The default naming strategy is to use same value as column name. To insert underscore, you can use ImprovedNamingStrategyDelegate(or ImprovedNamingStrategy).