# ORA-00904: invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, imp

I have used IMP utility to import the tables of a schema. The import was successful. But when I am checking the tables, for one table I am getting " ORA-00904: "to": invalid identifier " error. The column " To " is present in the table. I have imported the tables alone and it went successful and 6507 rows imported. But still I am facing the same error. I am facing this issue for the first time. Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TO` is a reserved word. there should be an option "use quoted identifiers" somewhere to set

Comment: Hi ..  Thanks for the response . The "TO" is mentioned in quotes only.

Comment: right; I think the quotes are part of the message template and do not indicate that the column name was properly quoted when executed. post the full IMP command. when you say, "when I am checking the tables", what do you mean (which command/utility generates the message)?

Comment: The error message says **ORA-00904: "to": invalid identifier**. But you say **The column " To "** . Note the case and the spaces. Please be very careful. One of the reasons why [double quotes are so pernicious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325) is that they condemn us to typing the quoted identifier *exactly*.