# Oracle condition that does not have a specific type of filter using EXISTS

Tags: oracle, subquery, conditional-statements, exists

I want to perform an `EXISTS` condition on a procedure:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT ContractType FROM VW_CONTRACT 
            WHERE "EmployeeId" = ACTIVITY. "EmployeeId" 
            AND UPPER (ContractType) IN ('SPECIAL TYPE') 
            AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

But the SPECIAL TYPE is not a type present in the `ContractType` column in `VW_CONTRACT`, it exists only in the screen filters, and is treated on the procedure. When I have an employee allocated in an activity, but without a contract with the company, the SPECIAL TYPE of contract is returned (NVL). The employee does not have a contract, so it is not in the table `VM_CONTRATO`. That way this condition is not met when filtering by this type.

How do I also consider the SPECIAL TYPE in that case? I've tried a few ways, but they have not worked. Any tips or recommendations?

The purpose is for me to consult `VM_CONTRATO` to see if the employee has any of the contract types of the selected filter for the `ACTIVITIES` where the employee is allocated.

Ex:

Table ACTIVITY:

```
Id EmployeeId  NameActivity
-- ----------  -----------
1  Employee1      Act1    
2  Employee2      Act2
3  Employee3      Act3
```

Table VM_CONTRACT:

```
Id EmployeeId  TypeContract
-- ----------  ------------
1  Employee1      Type 1
2  Employee2      Type 2
```

If I query the activities all three activities would be returned, if I filter by the SPECIAL TYPE of activity, employee3 should continue to be returned, which is not the case currently.

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry if I was not clear, here are some more details.

This is a template of the query structure generated by the procedure. The commented code was the form used to perform the "Bond" filter (parameter sent by the user). But, it was necessary to change the context of the filter so as not to filter the whole result based on the parameter sent, but rather to identify if the employee or employees had that "Bond", to return all the ALLOCATIONS of them. An employee may have had more than one type of link in the time period surveyed.

Then the EXISTS code was added, but it does not work for the "SPECIAL TYPE" filter type. Because in this case the employee does not have a contract, but is providing a service (he is allocated in an activity)

I need a way to create a single condition that meets both existing filters and the "SPECIAL TYPE" filter.

```
SELECT FILTER.* 
FROM ( 
    SELECT NVL((SELECT TypeContract FROM VW_CONTRACT WHERE "EmployeeId" = CONTRACT_ALOC."EmployeeId" AND ROWNUM = 1), 'SPECIAL TYPE') as "Bond",
           CONTRACT_ALOC.*
    FROM (SELECT ACTIVITY.* 
            FROM
               (SELECT *
                FROM OTHER TABLES 
                WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS
                union all        
                SELECT *
                FROM ( 
                    SELECT *
                    FROM    OTHER TABLES 2
                    WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS 2
                    ) ACTIVITY_IRHP
                WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS 3
                ) ACTIVITY
                WHERE   TO_DATE('01/09/2000', 'DD/MM/RRRR') BETWEEN ACTIVITY."InicialDate" AND ACTIVITY."FinalDate" 
                        AND EXISTS (SELECT NVL(TypeContract, 'SPECIAL TYPE') FROM VW_CONTRACT WHERE "EmployeeId" = ACTIVITY."EmployeeId" AND UPPER(TypeContract) IN ( 'SPECIAL TYPE' ) AND ROWNUM = 1)
                        AND ACTIVITY."EmployeeId" IN (3263) 
                        ) CONTRACT_ALOC
                       ORDER BY CONTRACT_ALOC."EmployeeName") FILTER;
                       --WHERE LOWER("Bond") IN ( 'SPECIAL TYPE' );
```

Comment: You say, "I've tried a few ways, but they have not worked.". Show us what you've tried. And what do you mean by " and is treated on the procedure"?.Please elaborate.

Comment: You want to filter your data by querying a view which you know doesn't contain the value you're searching for? Fnord. You need to explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I added more details if you can take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is rather unclear. However it seems likely that what you need is an outer join between the table and the view:

```
select t.id 
       , t."EmployeeId" 
       , t.NameActivity
       , nvl(v.contracttype, 'SPECIAL TYPE') as contracttype
from activity t
     left outer join vm_contract v
     on t."EmployeeId" = v."EmployeeId"
```

So this query returns all the employees recorded in ACTIVITY; all those employees who don't match a record in VM_CONTRACT are assigned a contract type of 'SPECIAL TYPE'.

Obviously you'll need to edit this query to fit all the other places where identifier names are defined using [those abominable double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I was instructed to make a solution for when the SPECIAL TYPE is passed as parameter, add a line NOT EXIST, as code below. That way it does not stop returning cases of this type. I tested it and it worked for what I needed.

Thank you for your help.

```
    SELECT FILTER.* 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT NVL((SELECT TypeContract FROM VW_CONTRACT WHERE "EmployeeId" = CONTRACT_ALOC."EmployeeId" AND ROWNUM = 1), 'SPECIAL TYPE') as "Bond",
               CONTRACT_ALOC.*
        FROM (SELECT ACTIVITY.* 
                FROM
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM OTHER TABLES 
                    WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS
                    union all        
                    SELECT *
                    FROM ( 
                        SELECT *
                        FROM    OTHER TABLES 2
                        WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS 2
                        ) ACTIVITY_IRHP
                    WHERE OTHER CONDITIONS 3
                    ) ACTIVITY
                    WHERE   TO_DATE('01/09/2000', 'DD/MM/RRRR') BETWEEN ACTIVITY."InicialDate" AND ACTIVITY."FinalDate" 
                            AND (EXISTS (SELECT NVL(TypeContract, 'SPECIAL TYPE') FROM VW_CONTRACT WHERE "EmployeeId" = ACTIVITY."EmployeeId" AND UPPER(TypeContract) IN ( 'SPECIAL TYPE' ) AND ROWNUM = 1)
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT NVL(TypeContract, 'SPECIAL TYPE') FROM VW_CONTRACT WHERE "EmployeeId" = ACTIVITY."EmployeeId")
                            AND ACTIVITY."EmployeeId" IN (1234) 
                            ) CONTRACT_ALOC
                           ORDER BY CONTRACT_ALOC."EmployeeName") FILTER;
                           --WHERE LOWER("Bond") IN ( 'SPECIAL TYPE' );
```