# Oracle-00904 Exception: Invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

#### EDIT:: Using the new Query provided by Thorsten Kettner solved my original problem.

Comment: "invalid identificator" sounds like a typo in a variable's name

Comment: Can you show us the final strings as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

Comment: Could you please provide value of `agentIdSubQuery`?

Comment: string agentIdSubQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT AGENT_ID FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION WHERE LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5";

Comment: Check updated post now for newest error.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you have

```
max(DISTINCT AGENT_ID)
```

The `DISTINCT` is superfluous, because `MAX(DISTINCT value)` and `MAX(ALL value)` is the same of course, but most of all, this expression has no explicit name! (Oracle will create one on-the-fly; probably something like `MAX_DISTINCT_AGENT_ID`). Make this

```
max(AGENT_ID) as AGENT_ID
```

in order to access it later by that name.

Comment: Thank you, now my program isn't crashing anymore, but it won't find the teams in my program either? My original code is in my original post edited.

Comment: Are there `AGENT_INITIALS` with a length less than five characters and the applied allocation range in your table? What does the first query return?

Comment: The very first Query worked fine, but showed an outdated department for an employee, instead of his newest/active department. So i made the Query you see here, which started crashing my program, and now your code fix is making my program run but not showing employees. in my agent tree view.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to what you are asking, but maybe you want to ask something else :-)

If all you want is the latest entry per agent, then use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your columns from newest to oldest per agent and only keep those rows ranked "newest":

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    aa.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY allocation_start DESC) AS rn
  FROM ks_drift.v_agent_allocation aa
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: That looks exactly as what i need, can you insert it into the Query 2 code snippet? Then i'll test if it Works.

Comment: I tried making it in C# but failed as I am not sure how to write it.

Comment: string sql = "SELECT * " + "FROM " + "(" + "SELECT aa.*, ROW_NUMBER()" + "OVER (PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY allocation_start DESC) AS rn FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION aa)"
                    + ")" + "WHERE rn = 1";

Comment: By the way: I would always write and test queries with an appropriate tool (e.g. SQL Developer), before putting them in some program code.

Comment: Thank you for your help its now fixed.

Comment: I now get a NullReferenceException when trying to choose a single agent in my checkbox tree with the new code that you provided. Have any idea how to fix that @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: @Pokemon Master1: No, sorry, I have no idea what is causing the error.

Comment: The exact query i use is this: 

 string sql = "select * from( SELECT age1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY age1.agent_id ORDER BY age1.allocation_start DESC) AS rn FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age1 INNER JOIN (" + agentIdSubQuery +") age2 ON age1.AGENT_ID = age2.AGENT_ID ORDER BY AGENT_INITIALS) where rn=1";

Comment: The only thing that I see is that `ORDER BY AGENT_INITIALS` within the subquery makes no sense. It belongs at the end of the query (after `where rn=1`). On a sidenote: For readability I would never join when only checking for existence. I'd rather use an `IN` clause (or `EXISTS` for that matter): `WHERE age1.AGENT_ID in (select agent_id from ...)`.

Comment: I really don't know.

Comment: I found out the crash had nothing to do with your query, thank you alot for helping.