# Sum of count in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm beginner in Oracle and I was wondering why I cannot make sum out of count function. Here's the example of my queries and tries:

```
select job_id, SUM(count(job_id)) as "jobs" 
from employees 
group by job_id
```

error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

I also tried to use cte but to my surprise I can't:

```
with cte1 as (
  select job_id, count(job_id) as "jobs" 
  from employees 
  group by job_id
)
select sum(jobs) from cte1
```

> ORA-00904: "JOBS": invalid identifier

Comment: The CTE doesn't work because you have used a lower-case identifier in double-quotes but you don't include the double-quotes when you referenced the CTE in the main query. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest aggregates. But you need to remove the columns you're grouping by from the select list:

```
select sum(count(*)) as "jobs" 
from   hr.employees 
group  by job_id;

jobs   
   107
```

This counts the number of rows for each job. And then sums these up.

Which is the same as:

```
with jobs as ( 
  select count(*) c
  from   hr.employees 
  group  by job_id
)
  select sum ( c ) from jobs;

SUM(C)   
     107
```

Your CTE is failing because you've quoted "jobs". This makes it a lowercase identifier you need to reference in quotes to access:

```
with cte1 as(
  select job_id,
         count( job_id ) as "jobs"
  from   hr.employees
  group by job_id
)
  select sum( "jobs" )
  from   cte1;

SUM("JOBS")   
          107
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but what's the difference between alias in quotation marks and without it. I thought I have to put it in quotation marks. Now I'm confused where I have to use them (quotation marks) and where I don't

Comment: Quoting identifiers make them case sensitive. But you only have to use them in Oracle Database to access lowercase identifiers. So it's generally easier to avoid quoting names

Comment: So there is no situations in Oracle db when i have to use quoting? I was working in ms sql before and there was plenty of them

Comment: If you want to access a lowercase name, you have to use quotes. Same if you want to use characters other than alphanumeric, _, $ or #. It's rare you'll encounter this though. Provided you're not quoting identifiers ;)

Comment: Ok, and what about apostrophe? I see that it's been used in where statement and where else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want an apostrophe in a table/column name, you need to double quote it. Values between two single quotes are text literals.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the redundant sum, you already have count of rows per job_id:

```
select job_id, count(job_id) as "jobs" from employees group by job_id
```