# PLS-00302: component 'VARIABLE_SKU_ID' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to store result of my query into a variable so that i can use it in another query, but getting errors

```
create procedure store_validated_sku_id
("variable_sku_id" VARCHAR2)
as
BEGIN

SELECT vsku.SKU_ID INTO  store_validated_sku_id.variable_sku_id 
FROM vs_sku_discont_details_test discontd,vsx_dcs_sku vsku,auto_ship_view bcc 
where discontd.sku_id = vsku.JDA_SKU_ID 
  and bcc.sku_id = vsku.SKU_ID AND vsku.web_eligible = 1 
  and vsku.discontinued =0 and bcc.auto_ship_eligible is null;

END store_validated_sku_id;

/
```

Getting the following errors in compiler logs:

```
Error(5,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5,49): PLS-00302: component 'VARIABLE_SKU_ID' must be declared
Error(5,65): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Comment: See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030439/146325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE store_validated_sku_id( variable_sku_id OUT VARCHAR2 ) IS    
BEGIN    
  SELECT vsku.SKU_ID
    INTO variable_sku_id      
    FROM vs_sku_discont_details_test discontd      
    JOIN vsx_dcs_sku vsku      
      ON discontd.sku_id = vsku.JDA_SKU_ID      
    JOIN auto_ship_view bcc      
      ON bcc.sku_id = vsku.SKU_ID      
   WHERE vsku.web_eligible = 1            
     AND vsku.discontinued = 0            
     AND bcc.auto_ship_eligible is null;    
END store_validated_sku_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting `variable_sku_id` between double quotes makes the identifier name case-sensitive.

Remove the double quotes, and it should be fine (I've changed your query to use ANSI-92 syntax - putting everything in the `FROM` clause is outdated old-style Oracle syntax and should be avoided):

```
create procedure store_validated_sku_id
(variable_sku_id VARCHAR2)
as 
BEGIN

SELECT vsku.SKU_ID INTO  store_validated_sku_id.variable_sku_id 
FROM vs_sku_discont_details_test discontd
JOIN vsx_dcs_sku vsku 
  ON  discontd.sku_id = vsku.JDA_SKU_ID 
JOIN auto_ship_view bcc
  ON bcc.sku_id = vsku.SKU_ID 
 WHERE vsku.web_eligible = 1 
 AND vsku.discontinued = 0 
 AND bcc.auto_ship_eligible is null;

END store_validated_sku_id;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,i had to make slight modification though

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, your main issue is wrapping your variable(`variable_sku_id`)'s
  around with quotes(no matter double or single, both yields problem),
  you should get rid of them
- but also need to convert it to `out` or `in out` type, since a
  `in`(default) type argument **cannot be used as an assignment target**.

Comment: Good catch regarding the `out` / `in out` type, I completely missed that one.