# Oracle DB - ORA-00904: "invalid identifier" error on select

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-00904

I'm a novice to Oracle DB, and I'm getting an error that I can't quite understand.

I have two tables, table1 and table2, with the ID primary key field in table1 being a foreign key in table2.

Here's a query that works fine:

```sql
select c.* from table1 c
    inner join table2 c2 on c.ID = c2.RID
```

the problem is I'm trying to write a query that's more complex, and as soon as I add more tables to my query, i get this error `ORA-00904: C"."ID": invalid identifier`, which I get when I run the following:

```sql
select c.* from table1 c, table3 a, table4 b
    inner join table2 c2 on c.ID = c2.RID
```

I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier/6030439) for help but it didn't really help my case (unless I missed something, but I doubt it)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Because explicit join chains are evaluated before comma separated ones... I.e. your ON only has access to table4 and table2 columns.

Comment: Aside from your faulty join syntax it is really impossible to say without seeing the actual CREATE TABLE ddl for all tables involved.

Comment: It's telling you `table1` has no column called `"ID"`. I'd be inclined to believe it. A working test case would help a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pile the joins on eachother like:

```
select c.* 
from table1 c 
    inner join table2 c2 on c.ID = c2.RID
inner join table3 a on [c.ID = a.RID] --you have not provided the relations for this 
inner join table4 b on [c.ID = b.RID] --you have not provided the relations for this
```

if you still get an invalid identifier from c.ID, I would double-check if ID is actually the right column name.

Please provide the table definitions and how they should relate for a better answer