# Search from oracle database in Java using LIKE keyword

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
query="select * from books where BookName LIKE \"%" +txt1.getText()+"%\"";
```

this is for mysql server database code.
what will be change for oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have ORA-00904 even when the column is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722851/why-do-i-have-ora-00904-even-when-the-column-is-present)

Comment: There is multiple answers that cover multiple causes. Also, `pass` is not in the query, are you sure this is the one ?

Comment: Please learn how to use a  [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and read the chapter  [Basic Elements of Oracle SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217) on how to specify string literals in SQL

Comment: please use preparedstatement. your sql has risk about sql injection...

Comment: String literals in normal SQL dialects are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. And your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please learn how to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

**DO NOT** build SQL queries using string concatenation - you should be using bind parameters.

Your query string should be:

```
query="select * from books where BookName LIKE ?";
```

and then you can do something like:

```
Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" ); // If you are using the Oracle driver.

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
  "username",
  "password"
);

final String query="select * from books where BookName LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);            
ps.setString( 1, "%" + txt1.getText() + "%" );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
// Loop through the result set.
// Close statement/connections
```

*(you will need to handle exceptions, etc.)*

and:

- You should not need to change the query to swap between MySQL and Oracle (just change the driver and connection string).
- You do not need to escape any single or double quotation marks in the input string.
- You are protected from SQL injection attacks.
- Oracle can cache the query with the bind parameter and does not have to re-parse / re-compile it when the bind parameter changes.

If you are going to write the query as a string then string literals are surrounded by single quotes (not double quotes) in SQL:

```
query="select * from books where BookName LIKE '%your_string%'";
```

and you need to make sure that any single quotes in your string are properly escaped (but just use a bind parameter instead).

Comment: It would be better to handle JDBC resources with `try-with-resources`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Updated to just be a snippet relevant to the OP's question - this is just an answer on how to pass parameters to a query and increasing the scope to what is the current "proper" exception handling technique is a distraction from the answer to the question. Yes, the modern way is to use `try-with-resources` but this is not a Java tutorial so I have removed all the extraneous bits of code to just focus the answer on the question asked (and included a note in the text to remember exception handling).

Comment: I agree with the solution but the answer is to use `'` instead of `"`. This is only mentioned in the bullet point. This is hiding the problem. OPs could still write a query with a constant `String` like `"select * from persons where sex = \"M\""`. No parameters so no real reason to use a `PreparedStatement`. I feel this should be a bit more visible ;)

Comment: @AxelH Updated. But you should still use a bind parameter as it allows Oracle to cache the query and does not need to re-parse it when `sex = 'M'` changes to `sex = 'F'` if you just use `sex = ?`.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with this..

query="select * from books where BookName LIKE '%" +txt1.getText()+"%'";

thanks everyone :)