# Error ORA-00904 while calling procedure inside package using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I'm working on a PLSQL package that calls another PLSQL package that returns separated results (*i.e OUT variables*) as follows:

- (1) SYS_REFCURSOR
- (1) NUMBER
- (1) VARCHAR2

This is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=245b49561e7213f85d445db674de8d61) I build.

Full code of the linked dbfiddle:

> ```
> /* Main table - it contains the data to use in a cursor: */
> CREATE TABLE tpos_retbenf
> (
> id_serial NUMBER (9,0),
> serial_nmb NUMBER(12,0)
> );
> ```

> ```
> /* Destination of the records detected on "tpos_retbenf": */
> CREATE TABLE tbl_debug 
> (
> msg_text VARCHAR2(1000),
> record_date DATE
> );
> ```

> ```
> /* Add values to the main table: */
> INSERT INTO tpos_retbenf (id_serial, serial_nmb) 
> VALUES (1, 202108311635);
> ```

> ```
> /* Package that contains the code to execute: */
> create or replace PACKAGE                 PCK_POS_UNO is
>
> PROCEDURE SP_POS_UNO (ID_RECORD IN NUMBER,
>                                   CUR_RET_BENF OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
>                                   IDERROR OUT NUMBER,
>                                   DSERROR OUT VARCHAR2);
>
> end PCK_POS_UNO;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create or replace PACKAGE BODY                 PCK_POS_UNO is
>
> /* This is the procedure that returns results in separated variables: */
> PROCEDURE SP_POS_UNO (ID_RECORD IN NUMBER,
>                                   CUR_RET_BENF OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
>                                   IDERROR OUT NUMBER,
>                                   DSERROR OUT VARCHAR2) AS
>
>
> v_temp number(6) := 0;
> v_S varchar2(1) := 'S';
>
> BEGIN
>
>     if ID_RECORD is null or ID_RECORD <= 0 then
>       IDERROR := -1;
>       DSERROR := 'Id no valido para la operacion';
>       goto finalizar;
>     end if;
>
>     select count(1) into v_temp
>     from tpos_retbenf r
>     where r.id_serial = ID_RECORD;
>
>     if v_temp = 0 then
>       IDERROR := -1;
>       DSERROR := 'Id no encontrado';
>       goto finalizar;
>     end if;
>
>     OPEN CUR_RET_BENF FOR
>     select r.id_serial, r.serial_nmb
>     from tpos_retbenf r 
>      where r.id_serial = ID_RECORD;
>
>
> <<finalizar>>
>  null;
>
> END SP_POS_UNO;
>
> END PCK_POS_UNO;
> /
> ```

> ```
> /* Package that calls the "SP_POS_UNO" procedure from the "PCK_POS_UNO" package: */
> create or replace PACKAGE PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION IS
>   PROCEDURE ONLINENOVELTYBEN
>    (
>       V_NID_DEV IN NUMBER,  
>         CV_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
>     );
> END PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION IS 
> PROCEDURE ONLINENOVELTYBEN
> (
>   V_NID_DEV IN NUMBER,
>     CV_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
> ) IS
>     
>     V_USER VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) := 'INTERNET';
>     V_QUERY VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR);
>     -- Variables:
>     V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF SYS_REFCURSOR;
>     V_OUT_IDERROR NUMBER;
>     V_OUT_DSERROR VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR);
> BEGIN
>
>     /* 
>         Here, the "PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO" is called 
>         from "PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION" as follows:
>     */
>     V_QUERY := 'SELECT APPLICATION_POS.PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR) FROM DUAL';
>     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY INTO V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR USING V_NID_DEV, V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR ;
>     
>     /*
>       An this error occurs:
>       Error: ORA-00904: "PCK_POS_UNO"."SP_POS_UNO": invalid identifier - StackTrace: ORA-06512: in line 24
>     */
>
>     -- After getting the results in (V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR) variables, 
>     -- a LOOP is executed for retrieve the records in "V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF" cursor...
>     -- It doesn't continue here due to error shown above.
>
> END ONLINENOVELTYBEN;
>
> END PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION;
> /
> ```

When the following code is going to be executed:

```
V_QUERY := 'SELECT APPLICATION_POS.PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR) FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY INTO V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR USING V_NID_DEV, V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR ;
```

The error says:

> Error: ORA-00904: "APPLICATION_POS"."PCK_POS_UNO"."SP_POS_UNO": invalid identifier -
> StackTrace: ORA-06512: in line 24

---

I've tried so far:

- Search for `ORA-00904` error - in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723834/12511801) says "*proper permissions on objects involved in the query*" - which I share, but, I don't know how to argument this option (*since I can do a simple `SELECT` to that table and the results are shwon, hence, they might not accept this argument*). Related to this argument, I can't get listed the `PCK_POS_UNO` package "since the OWNER is different from the one I'm usually using (that is `APPLICATION`)".
- I made a copy of this package/procedure and was able to execute the procedure/package via SQL Developer - *see screenshot*, but, the same error `ORA-00904` occurs.

*Screentshot of the execution of the package:*

[image: screenshot]

*Results:*

[image]

- Change the code that calls the procedure that has `OUT` parameters, but, I'm unable to get a successful combination that allows the compilation and execution of the code as a whole.

Examples - all based on internet searchs and my own "instinct":

(1): Added (;) at the end of the dynamic-sql string:

```
V_QUERY := 'SELECT APPLICATION_POS.PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO((:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR) FROM DUAL;';
```

(2): Removing the OWNER - in this case "APPLICATION_POS":

```
V_QUERY := 'SELECT PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR) FROM DUAL';
```

(3): Calling the procedure directly - it shows `SP2-0552: bind variable "V_NID_DEV" not declared` - but, how?, in a separated sample, the variable "V_NID_DEV" is declared and with value "2462013":

```
PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR);
```

(4): Calling the procedure directly (*removing also the points*) - in this case, `ORA-01001 - invalid cursor` error is generated - which I think it doesn't make sense - since the OUT cursor is not being opened for read or operated somehow.

```
PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(V_NID_DEV, V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR);
```

I'm really run out of ideas - since I'm not familiar with this type of creating packages and passing values between packages and I didn't created this code.

Is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: You cannot `select` procedure result from something, because procedure doesn't return anything. So `select proc() from dual` is not a valid syntax. Correct way is `PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(V_NID_DEV, V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, V_OUT_IDERROR, V_OUT_DSERROR);`, because you pass PL/SQL variables, not bind variables. What about 4: it's hard to tell, what is wrong, because it works as expected. Check corrected [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=327b3469b56e43847700c6ed45993239)

Comment: Also please provide **minimal** reproducible example. Retyping all those long identifiers and nested procedures which does not use their input parameters is quite boring.

Comment: @astentx, that's how the code is (*not even mine*), working on legacy code, tbh.

Comment: But anyway, SO about specific focused problem. If you've spent enough time for debugging to locate the problematic peace of code and **can reproduce** the issue, then the surrounding code in this case will be a few lines. If you build your code from scratch, then you will definitely face the step after which the code doesn't work anymore. And in this specific case it is nearly at the very beginning (simple procedure with cursor opened for `select * from dual` with one in and out parameters).

Comment: @astentx also, I though I created a **minimal** reproducible example - trust me, this was the most compacted I could manage. I appreciate your help, honestly. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: GOTO  is a bad practice!
use RETURN

Comment: V_QUERY is wrong, because you cann't call a procedure inside a SELECT

Comment: Why use dynamic sql (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) to call procedure SP_POS_UNO? It seems useless, can you explain?

Comment: @alvalongo, Unfortunately, I can't explain why those packages where created/coded in that way = it's not my code. The problem with this code I'm checking is also a problem with the owner of the package: in my question I added `APPLICATION_POS.PCK_POS_UNO` where `APPLICATION_POS` is the owner of the `PCK_POS_UNO` package and, after applying the changes you put in your answer, I get another error: `PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_ONL_AFF_USR.GETONLINEAFFINFO' must be declared`.

Comment: @alvalongo cont. For this error, I send the script for create the `PKG_ONL_AFF_USR` package under the `APPLICATION_POS` owner - since this package exists with other owner called `APPLICATION`. I don't have any control about the database, hence, it's a struggle working in this way, but, it's the best I can do. +1 to your answer and I appreciate your help. Once this problem is solved (*or when I can move on with another issues*), I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package modified to call procedure SP_POS_UNO:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION
IS 
  PROCEDURE ONLINENOVELTYBEN(V_NID_DEV IN NUMBER,
                             CV_1      IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                            )
  IS
    V_USER  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) := 'INTERNET';
    V_QUERY VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR);
    -- Variables:
    V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    V_OUT_IDERROR        NUMBER;
    V_OUT_DSERROR       VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR);
  BEGIN
      /* 
          Here, the "PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO" is called 
          from "PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION" as follows:
      */
      V_QUERY:='Begin
 PCK_POS_UNO.SP_POS_UNO(:V_NID_DEV, :V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, :V_OUT_IDERROR, :V_OUT_DSERROR);
End;';
      --
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY
      USING     V_NID_DEV, 
            out V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF, 
            out V_OUT_IDERROR, 
            out V_OUT_DSERROR ;
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('V_OUT_IDERROR='||V_OUT_IDERROR);
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('V_OUT_DSERROR='||V_OUT_DSERROR);
      --
      CV_1:=V_OUT_CUR_RET_BENF;
  END ONLINENOVELTYBEN;
  --
END PKG_BH_ONLINE_INFORMATION;
```